# Draw Scatter Plots with different colors in Python

Tags: python, scatter-plot, colorbar

I am trying to draw a scatter plot(as shown in the attached image) between two variables with different colours and a colour bar as well. Can someone help in drawing a scatter plot as shown below?

[image]
simple scatter plot tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate some random data
x = np.random.randn(100)
y = np.random.randn(100)
colors = np.random.randn(100)

# Create scatter plot with different colors and color bar
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, c=colors, cmap='coolwarm')
plt.colorbar(scatter)

# Set axis labels and title
ax.set_xlabel('Variable 1')
ax.set_ylabel('Variable 2')
ax.set_title('Scatter Plot with Color Bar')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```